# I can add users to the Active users in the portal, but not to People and Groups - Sharepoint 2013 on Office365

Tags: security, groups, user-accounts

I'm using SharePoint 2013 on Office365.

I've added two users in the Admin Portal, both with identical attributes (except name, email address etc.!)

However, when I go onto my site and try to add them to the Members group, only one of them is available. The first image shows adding the user which I **CAN** add:

[image: Successfully adding a user]

This shows the one that I cannot make appear:

[image: Unsuccessfully adding a user]

If I complete the "unsuccessful" adding of the user, then the user receives an email inviting them to the site, but they don't appear in the list of Members:

[image: list of available users]

I'm at a loss to understand what I'm doing wrong.  The "successful" user Sam Wilson has exactly the same attributes as the "unsuccessful" user, except that SharePoint can find him in the list of users in the SharePoint users portal.

[image: list of Active users]

Comment: This site is for programming question *only*.

Comment: Ok, sorry.  I'll find somewhere else.